# After installing the yii2 advanced application template,running localhost/advanced/advanced/web doent display anything

Tags: php, yii2

```
   generate cookie validation key in frontend/config/main-local.php
      chmod 0777 backend/runtime
      chmod 0777 backend/web/assets
      chmod 0777 frontend/runtime
      chmod 0777 frontend/web/assets
      chmod 0755 yii
      chmod 0755 yii_test

  ... initialization completed.
```

The index.php file is present inside the folder advanced/advanced/frontend/index.php. But it is not displaying while localhost/advanced/advanced/frontend/index.php.

Comment: have you run the php init command

Comment: Yes .. After running php.init i got    like ......initialization completed.

Comment: Are you using urlManager for enablePrettyUrl?
if not the URL should be  **frontend/web/index.php**

Comment: else it should be **frontend/web**

Comment: If I do frontend/web also. Blank page.. I simply downloaded the the yii2 advanced application template then i run php init command

Comment: You should take a look at  the installation  procedure suggested  by YII2  ..  based  on composer

Comment: Yes I installed it successfully via composer